The "ddg_win" user agent
Recently in my server's Apache logs a user agent showed up: ddg_win. It only requests the /favicon.ico and does that repeatedly. I Google'd it but found no information as to what this is an why it is making the repeated requests.
Does anybody have some information on this user agent?
Here's an example from yesterday's logs:
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:14:46 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 555 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:14:50 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:14:51 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:15:18 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:15:18 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:15:21 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:15:22 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:16:03 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:16:04 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:16:08 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:47:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:48:04 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:48:04 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"
45.36.70.0 - - [18/Sep/2024:00:48:08 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 497 "-" "ddg_win"

+ 50 more just like this

I stumbled upon this as well. Could it be a DuckDuckGo Windows browser? But it seems strange that DuckDuckGo doesn't write anything about it on their homepage.
I have it blocked until I know more. The behaviour is strange. Looks like a bot.
